# mod_rewrite regex to match root level whole name page

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm want to rewrite many pages following the simple schema:

**old_page.php** to **content/new-page.php**

I got a problem when **apple.php** must be rewritten to **fruits/red-apple.php** because I get into a rewriting **loop**, so i have to match domain/apple.php

I'm not sure if I can set up RewriteRule or I'll also need rewriteCond ..

Answer (score 0):

You should show us what you're working with, but it sounds like your patterns are simply missing start and end of string anchors. E.g.:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^apple\.php$ fruits/red-apple.php [NS,L]
```

You may be better off using `RewriteMap` if you have a lot of rules.

Comment: even with start and end string anchors I got a redir loop because - i believe - the foder fruits phisically exists ..

Comment: `RewriteRule "^privacy_policy\.php$"   "/myfolder/privacy_policy.php"`

 myfolder phisically exists, and the new site is using  internal link with that path. My goad is to provide 301 redirects to paages who were on the root on the old site, and are still phiscally there but linked into **symlink** folders (myfolder) pointing back to the root

Comment: That's critical info. Apache is probably doing a subrequest after following the symlink, then matching the rule again. Voilà, infinite loop. I've added the `NS` flag to my answer, though, you should probably move the symlinked files to the subdirectory, for efficiency, anyway.